# MySQL takes forever after running certain php scripts... optimization help?

Tags: mysql, php, vbulletin

When I run a couple scripts from the vBulletin software (like uninstalling a plugin) it takes forever.

When monitoring the memory usage, it shows this =>

-/+ buffers/cache:        158        381
Swap:          255         10        245

It seems that MySQL is only using a certain amount and once it does it tries to use the swap instead?

I have a 512MB slice and right now my key buffer is at 16M and max_allowed_packet is at 16M.

Is there something else I should increase or can I increase those variables and still be safe?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your my.cnf :

```
max_connections = 650
key_buffer = 256M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 64M
join_buffer_size = 4M
read_buffer_size = 4M
sort_buffer_size = 4M
table_cache = 16384
thread_cache_size = 128
wait_timeout = 30
interactive_timeout = 300
connect_timeout = 10
tmp_table_size = 128M
max_allowed_packet = 32M
max_connect_errors = 999999999
thread_concurrency = 8
query_cache_limit = 1M
query_cache_size = 256M
query_cache_type = 1
query_prealloc_size = 16384
query_alloc_block_size = 16384
old_passwords = 1
tmpdir = /dev/shm
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 256M
```